# retrieving referenced objects in JSON from Android

Tags: java, android, json, wcf

```
{
 getJobDetailsResult: [
 {
   Client:
  {
    ClientID: 265,
    ClientName: "RETRAVISION (WA) LTD"
  },
   ConsignmentActive: true,
   ConsignmentCreationDate: "6/06/2012",
   ConsignmentCustRef: "855929",
   ConsignmentID: 304005,
   OrderNo: "20807354",
  ShipTo:
  {
    ShipToAddress1: "c/o HELENWAY ",
    ShipToAddress2: "WHS E4 UNIT 12 MARKET CITY ",
    ShipToCity: "CANNINGVALE",
    ShipToContactName: null,
    ShipToId: 18933,
    ShipToName: "DALWALLINU RETRAVISION 2",
    ShipToPCode: "6155",
    ShipToState: "WA"
   }
}
]
}
```

Hi guys, I am currently trying to retrieve JSON using Android, and so far, I've had no trouble. However, I have one small issue, and that has to do with retrieving objects that the Consignment class references to, namely the ShipTo and Client classes.

So far, I am able to retrieve the Consignment values like the ConsignmentActive, ConsignmentCreationDate, ConsignmentCustRef, ConsignmentID, and OrderNo. However, I am not sure how to map the items from the ShipTo and Client.

This is my current code, which I am trying to execute in a method:-

```
public Consignments getConsignmentManifest(String consignment)
{
    Consignments con = new Consignments();

    try
    {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String theString = new String("");
        //http get request
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(POD_URI + "/getJobDetails/" + consignment);
        //set the hedear to get the data in JSON format
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        //get the response
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            builder.append(line);
        }
        is.close();

        theString = builder.toString();

        JSONObject conJSON = new JSONObject(theString);
        JSONArray cons = conJSON.getJSONArray("getJobDetailsResult");

        for(int i = 0; i < cons.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject cObj = cons.getJSONObject(i);
            con.ConsignmentID = cObj.getInt("ConsignmentID");
            con.ConsignmentCreationDate = cObj.getString("ConsignmentCreationDate");
            con.ConsignmentCustRef = cObj.getString("ConsignmentCustRef");
            con.OrderNo = cObj.getString("OrderNo");
            con.ConsignmentActive = cObj.getBoolean("ConsignmentActive");

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return con;
}
```

I am keen to know how I can retrieve the ShipTo objects from here. I've tried something of this sort but I got an exception:-

```
con.Clients.ClientID = con.getint("ClientID");
```

Can someone show me how to improve this? All help will be appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: I've already figured out the problem. Here is the code:-

```
//Client object
                Clients cl = new Clients();
                cl.ClientId = clObj.getInt("ClientID");
                cl.ClientName = clObj.getString("ClientName");
                con.Clients = cl;

                //ShipTo object
                JSONObject stObj = cObj.getJSONObject("ShipTo");
                ShipTo sto = new ShipTo();
                sto.ShipToId = stObj.getInt("ShipToId");
                sto.ShipToName = stObj.getString("ShipToName");
                sto.ShipToAddress1 = stObj.getString("ShipToAddress1");
                sto.ShipToAddress2 = stObj.getString("ShipToAddress2");
                sto.ShipToCity = stObj.getString("ShipToCity");
                sto.ShipToPostcode = stObj.getString("ShipToPCode");
                sto.ShipToState = stObj.getString("ShipToState");
                con.ShipTo = sto;
```

All 3 objects; my Consignment, ShipTo, and Clients objects in Android are now being populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parse the response like this

```
String response = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

After getting the response create a **json object** from the response like this

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
```

You can get the final result like this

```
    String result1 = ((JSONArray) json.get("ShipTo")).getJSONObject(0)
        .getString("ShipToAddress1");
String result2 = ((JSONArray) json.get("ShipTo")).getJSONObject(0)
        .getString("ShipToAddress2");
```

Try this ,it will work.